# Do domain service accounts benefit from cached credentials?

Tags: active-directory, windows-service, credentials

When a domain user successfully logs on to a domain-joined computer, the user's domain credentials are cached so that the user can logon again if the domain controller is unavailable (eg the computer is disconnected from the network).

If the domain-joined computer is running a Windows service as a domain service account and the computer restarts, will the service start if there is no domain controller available?

Secondly, if the afore mentioned service attempts to authenticate to and communinicate with a second local service, will it succeed?

Answer (score 5):

I'm 90% certain that cached credentials apply only to interactive logins.

Comment: My experience as well, like MSSQL or Exchange services in domain user context not starting if there're no DCs around at all on bootup... though YMMV

Comment: I'm 99.9% certain it's interactive logins only.

Comment: @Oskar: all Exchange services usually run as LocalSystem, LocalService or NetworkService; they don't start if there's no DC around because Exchange relies *quite heavily* on Active Directory, not due to authentication failures. Just wanted to point this out :-)

Comment: Yeah I was gonna remove the Exchange mentioning from the comment and then forgot... ^^

Answer (score 1):

It is for interactive logons only. See the [MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913485).

Answer (score 0):

Cached credentials applies to services as well.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994565(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994565(v=ws.10).aspx it is only for "Account passwords for Windows services that are configured on the computer". Not for all applications.

> LSA secrets on the hard disk drive
>
> A Local Security Authority (LSA) secret is a secret piece of data that
>   is accessible only to SYSTEM account processes. Some of these secrets
>   are credentials that must persist after reboot, and they are stored in
>   encrypted form on the hard disk drive. Credentials stored as LSA
>   secrets might include:
>
> ```
> Account password for the computer’s AD DS account
>
> Account passwords for Windows services that are configured on the computer
>
> Account passwords for configured scheduled tasks
>
> Account passwords for IIS application pools and websites
> ```